# react hooks setTimeout after setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently wanted to design an input component with react hooks.
The component would check validation after entering input in 0.5 second.

my code like

```
const inputField = ({ name, type, hint, inputValue, setInput }) => {

    // if there is default value, set default value to state
    const [value, setValue] = useState(inputValue);

    // all of validation are true for testing
    const validCheck = () => true;

   let timeout;

    const handleChange = e => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        const v = e.target.value;

        setValue(v);

        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // if valid
            if (validCheck()) {
               // do something...
            }
        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <SCinputField>
            <input type={type} onChange={handleChange} />
       </SCinputField>
    );
};
```

unfortunately, it's not worked, because the timeout variable would renew every time after setValue.

I found react-hooks provide some feature like useRef to store variable.

Should I use it or shouldn't use react-hooks in this case?

**Update**

add useEffect

```
const inputField = ({ name, type, hint, inputValue, setInput }) => {

    // if there is default value, set default value to state
    const [value, setValue] = useState(inputValue);

    // all of validation are true for testing
    const validCheck = () => true;

   let timeout;

    const handleChange = e => {
        const v = e.target.value;

        setValue(v);
    };

    // handle timeout
    useEffect(() => {
        let timeout;

        if (inputValue !== value) {
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                const valid = validCheck(value);
                console.log('fire after a moment');

                setInput({
                    key: name,
                    valid,
                    value
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
    });


    return (
        <SCinputField>
            <input type={type} onChange={handleChange} />
       </SCinputField>
    );
};
```

It looks worked, but I am not sure about it's a right way to use.

Comment: use ```useEffect``` instead

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function InputField() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');       // STATE FOR THE INPUT VALUE
  const timeoutRef = useRef(null);              // REF TO KEEP TRACK OF THE TIMEOUT

  function validate() {                         // VALIDATE FUNCTION
    console.log('Validating after 500ms...');
  }

  useEffect(() => {                             // EFFECT TO RUN AFTER CHANGE IN VALUE
    if (timeoutRef.current !== null) {          // IF THERE'S A RUNNING TIMEOUT
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);         // THEN, CANCEL IT
    }

    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(()=> {      // SET A TIMEOUT
      timeoutRef.current = null;                // RESET REF TO NULL WHEN IT RUNS
      value !== '' ? validate() : null;         // VALIDATE ANY NON-EMPTY VALUE
    },500);                                     // AFTER 500ms
  },[value]);                                   // RUN EFFECT AFTER CHANGE IN VALUE

  return(                                       // SIMPLE TEXT INPUT
    <input type='text' 
      value={value} 
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );

}
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE ON SNIPPET BELOW:**

```js
function InputField() {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);

  function validate() {
    console.log('Validating after 500ms...');
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timeoutRef.current !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
     
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(()=> {
      timeoutRef.current = null;
      value !== '' ? validate() : null;
    },500);
  },[value]);
  
  return(
    <input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
  );
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputField/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but timeoutRef.current = null in setTimeout is necessary?

Comment: You're right. It's not necessary. Because you can reset the timeout on the same variable without any problems. Just edited that line out and it works fine! Thanks

Comment: Actually I added that line back. I think it's good practice to set your ref back to null when you're done using it in this case. Sure it works without it. But doing this way you can check for `if (timeoutRef.current)` and you'll get `false` if your timeout has already run. If you don't set it null, I think you would get `true` even if your timeout has already run.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to keep the reference to the timeout between renders. You can just return a function from the `useEffect` to clear it:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(()=> {
    if (value !== '') {
      validate();
    }
  }, 500);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);  // this guarantees to run right before the next effect
  }
},[value, validate]);
```

Also, don't forget to pass all the dependencies to the effect, including the `validate` function.

Ideally, you would pass the `value` as a parameter to the validate function: `validate(value)` - this way, the function has fewer dependencies, and could even be pure and moved outside the component.

Alternatively, if you have internal dependencies (like another `setState` or an `onError` callback from `props`), create the `validate` function with a `useCallback()` hook :

```
const validate = useCallback((value) => {
  // do something with the `value` state
  if ( /* value is NOT valid */ ) {
    onError(); // call the props for an error
  } else {
    onValid();
  }
}, [onError, onValid]); // and any other dependencies your function may use
```

This will keep the same function reference between the renders if the dependencies don't change.

Answer (score -1):

You can **move** timeout variable **inside** **handleChange** method.

```
const inputField = ({ name, type, hint, inputValue, setInput }) => {

// if there is default value, set default value to state
const [value, setValue] = useState(inputValue);

// all of validation are true for testing
const validCheck = () => true;

const handleChange = e => {


    let timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    const v = e.target.value;

    setValue(v);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // if valid
        if (validCheck()) {
           // do something...
        }
    }, 500);
};

return (
    <SCinputField>
        <input type={type} onChange={handleChange} />
   </SCinputField>
);
```

};

Comment: Sorry, I try this and show console.log, but got  the times I input. Maybe the clearTimeout is not worked well.

Comment: That's because the `timeout` variable only lives in the instance of the `handleChange` function. On a new render of the component, `handleChange` will be a new function, which has its own `timeout` variable, not knowing anything about the previous one. So `clearTimeout(timeout)` doesn't have any effect, the previously set timeout will still fire.